# select count subquery in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, jasper-reports

Here is my query in MongoDB:

```
{ runCommand : 
    { aggregate : 'record', 
      pipeline : [ 
        {  $match : {  "_id" : {
              "$binary" : "HUjjlL5SCpVKNVnedOk+nQ==", "$type" : "3"
              }}},
        { $project : { Results : 1 }},
        { $unwind  : '$Results'}
       ],
     cursor: {}
}
}
```

I want to add a subquery to COUNT results where `"Result.Type" = "SpecificResult"`.

Here is Document example:

```
{
"_id": Binary("HUjjlL5SCpVKNVnedOk+nQ==", 3),
"Header": {
    "FileFormatVersion": "2.0",
    "Filename": "1231434534654",
    "ReferenceNumber": "235423645677"
},
"Results": [
    {
        "Type": "Title",
        "Seq": "1111",
        "Title": "Some Title",
        "SubTitle": "",
        "TitleLevel": "1"
    },
    {
        "Type": "Title",
        "Seq": "056330010",
        "Title": "Some Subtitle",
        "SubTitle": "",
        "TitleLevel": "2"
    },
    {
        "Type": "Result",
        "Seq": "0560002200040",
        "ResultValue": "value"
    },
     {
        "Type": "SpecificResult",
        "Seq": "0123234010",
        "Title": "",
        "Name": "Name",
        "ResultComments": "Comment1"
    },
     {
        "Type": "SpecificResult",
        "Seq": "0123234010",
        "Title": "",
        "Name": "Name222",
        "ResultComments": "Comment1"
    }
]
}
```

In SQL it's looks like:

```
SELECT *, (select count (*) from Results where Type = 'SpecificResult') FROM Results;
```

How to do this in MongoDB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `$filter` to iterate loop of `Results.Type` array, check condition if type match with `SpecificResult`, `$size` to get count of returned result from `$filter`,

```
{ 
    runCommand : { 
        aggregate : 'record', 
        pipeline : [ 
            { $match : { "_id" : { "$binary" : "HUjjlL5SCpVKNVnedOk+nQ==", "$type" : "3" } } },
            { 
                $project : { 
                    Results : 1,
                    ResultCount: {
                        $size: {
                            $filter: {
                                input: "$Results.Type",
                                cond: { $eq:["$$this", "SpecificResult"] }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            { $unwind  : '$Results' }
        ],
        cursor: {}
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But how to insert this into my query? Can you please post 
whole query?

Comment: I am not sure what type of syntax you are using, you have to post your sample document,

Comment: Using https://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/jaspersoft-mongodb-query-language

Comment: can you please provide sample document of your schema/collection

Comment: Added an example of a document.

Comment: i have updated the answer, i have not tested but i have converted as per documentation of your reference